# How to tunnel Windows Remote Dektop through two machines

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, tunnel

I have the following situation - I actually made this little diagram for you:

[image]

**Which commands** do I need to issue **where** in order to be able to remote access the Windows XP machine "B"? I know that it is firewalled and thus I can only get to it via computer "A".

On my client side, I can use OS X or Windows 7, that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh -L3390:address-of-machine-b-from-a:3389 user-at-machine-a@address-of-machine-a
```

Then RDP will be available locally at port 3390.

Comment: That would be in OS/X that would.