# Using SSH to get around Remote Access block

Tags: command-line, ssh, port-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tunnel Windows Remote Dektop through two machines](https://superuser.com/questions/256357/how-to-tunnel-windows-remote-dektop-through-two-machines)

I've been reading about SSH port forwarding.  It sounds like I can route a service through a different port than it is used to being run through (normally for security reasons).  I also cant find any information online about SSH command line commands.  Does anybody know how to do this with say... the windows Remote Desktop tool?  I can get the CMD fine.

Thanks if you can!

Comment: Maybe that's what you want? [How to tunnel Windows Remote Dektop through two machines](http://superuser.com/questions/256357/how-to-tunnel-windows-remote-dektop-through-two-machines) - also I highly doubt you didn't find SSH command line usage help. Tried `man ssh`? (If you're on *nix, that is)

Comment: Thanks for the help, doubting me was not part of the question, however.  I'm using windows.  Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean it that way :) SSH is just very well documented imo. If the other question answered yours then let's just close this as a duplicate.